# i want to display image in fix size in table cell

Tags: iphone

in my iphone application images are comming from xml feed and they have variant size,how can  i resize them to fix width and hight programmatically.

my code is in which i want to display images in cell of same width and size.my image are comming from rss fedd.

```
int blogEntryIndex1 = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] -1];

imgstring=[[blogEntries objectAtIndex: blogEntryIndex1] objectForKey: @"image"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imgstring];


NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
cell.imageView.image=img;
```

please help me out if you can thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hi change your code like this,

```
 NSString *imgstring =[[blogEntries objectAtIndex: blogEntryIndex1] objectForKey:     @"image"]; 

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imgstring];

 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

 UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

 UIImageView *subview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f,60.0f, 60.0f)];

 [subview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:img]]; 

 [subview setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];

 [cell.contentView addSubView:subview];
```

try this one. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks nathan for reply
but my image is are comming from rss feed in xml
so i need a code for all images

Comment: currently my code is
    NSString *imgstring =[[blogEntries objectAtIndex: blogEntryIndex1] objectForKey: @"image"];
//then i extract image from url 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imgstring];
 NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
//now em gona display it in cell
cell.imageView.image=img;

Comment: Hi 

thanks for editing code but its still not working and i am reciving 4 warning 
my application crash and give me follwoing error

 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UIImage length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b36f50'